# ASP MVC Model ID not passing into actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

My view is not getting the models ID inside of the edit/details actionlink that was auto generated. Instead it just links me to hostname/controller/id instead of; hostname/controller/details/id

For the most part its just using the auto generated code; not much has changed - just adding in searching & sorting, etc.

I have no doubt that it's something incredibly stupid!

Thanks guys

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SMS_ADM.Models
{
    public class Logger
    {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Serial is required - This is the ID number of the weather station.")]        
        [DisplayName("Station Serial")]        
        public int Serial { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Friendly Name")]
        public string Friendlyname { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required - Please select the location where the weather station physically resides.")]
        [DisplayName("Location")]
        public int Locationid { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Location")]
        public virtual Location Location { get; set; }       

    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SMS_ADM.Models;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;

namespace SMS_ADM.Controllers
{
    public class LoggersController : Controller
    {
        private SmsadmContext db = new SmsadmContext();

        // GET: Loggers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var loggers = db.Loggers.Include(l => l.Location);

         return View(loggers.ToList());

          //  return View();

        }

        // GET: Loggers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Logger logger = db.Loggers.Find(Id);
            if (logger == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(logger);
        }

        // GET: Loggers/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.locationid = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(db.Locations, "Id", "locationname");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Loggers/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "serial,friendlyname,locationid")] Logger logger, Logger model)
        {
            ViewBag.locationid = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(db.Locations, "Id", "locationname");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (db.Loggers.Any(o => o.Serial == logger.Serial))
                {
                    //exists
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Weather station serial number already exists in system.");
                    return View();
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Loggers.Add(logger);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            return View(logger);
        }

        // GET: Loggers/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Logger logger = db.Loggers.Find(Id);
            if (logger == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.locationid = new SelectList(db.Locations, "Id", "locationcode", logger.Locationid);
            return View(logger);
        }

        // POST: Loggers/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,serial,friendlyname,locationid")] Logger logger)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(logger).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.locationid = new SelectList(db.Locations, "Id", "locationcode", logger.Locationid);
            return View(logger);
        }

        // GET: Loggers/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? Id)
        {
            if (Id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Logger logger = db.Loggers.Find(Id);
            if (logger == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(logger);
        }

        // POST: Loggers/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int Id)
        {
            Logger logger = db.Loggers.Find(Id);
            db.Loggers.Remove(logger);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SMS_ADM.Models.Logger>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Weather Stations List";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.title</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Register New Weather Station", "Create")
</p>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Search: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("DBID", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.lcodeSortParm })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Location Code", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.lcodeSortParm})
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Serial", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.serialSortParm})
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Friendly Name", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.fnameSortParm})
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Site", "Index", new {sortOrder = ViewBag.siteSortParm})
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Locationcode)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Serial)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Friendlyname)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location.Site)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {Id = item.Id}, null) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {Id = item.Id}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {Id = item.Id})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I found it within minutes after posting this ...

For anyone having the same issue as me this is something to check.

For some reason (Unknown to me now!) i changed my RouteConfig.cs file to take out ID. So I changes this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

to -

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```